# Oracle sequence not visible when created by ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, oracle, activerecord

I'm using ActiveRecord migrations to create tables and sequences in an Oracle database, but I can't use the sequences that it creates.

Here's a simple migration that I tried:

```
class CreateFoo < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def self.up
     create_table "FOO" do |t|
       t.string   "name",     :limit => 50
       t.integer  "age"
     end
   end

   def self.down
     drop_table "FOO"
   end
end
```

However, when I try to insert a record in that table, it can't find the sequence.

```
SQL> insert into foo values(foo_seq.nextval, 'bob', 10);
insert into foo values(foo_seq.nextval, 'bob', 10)
                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

The sequence does exist, but the name is mixed case. Is Oracle case sensitive?

```
SQL> select sequence_name from user_sequences;

SEQUENCE_NAME
------------------------------
FOO_seq
```

Changing the case of the sequence name to match doesn't help.

```
SQL> insert into foo values(FOO_seq.nextval, 'bob', 10);
insert into foo values(FOO_seq.nextval, 'bob', 10)
                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

How can I get ActiveRecord to go back to creating normal sequences? This used to work for me, but that may have been on an older version of ActiveRecord. I'm now using activerecord 4.0.13 and activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter 1.5.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Problem

After doing some research, I found that Oracle objects can have case-sensitive names if you use [quotes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm) when you create the object.

> 8. Nonquoted identifiers are not case sensitive. Oracle interprets them as uppercase. Quoted identifiers are case sensitive.

So I can use the sequence if I quote its name.

```
SQL> insert into foo values("FOO_seq".nextval, 'bob', 10);

1 row created.
```

Fine, I understand what Oracle is doing, but why is ActiveRecord using quotes when it creates the sequence? After digging into the activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter source code, I found the cause. To create the sequence name, it appends "_seq" to the table name. Because the result is mixed-case, it adds quotes.

### The Solution

Just switch the table name to lower case in the migration, then the whole sequence name will be lower case, and it won't get quoted. That will leave it case insensitive.

```
class CreateFoo < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def self.up
     create_table "foo" do |t|
       t.string   "name",     :limit => 50
       t.integer  "age"
     end
   end

   def self.down
     drop_table "foo"
   end
end
```